# Rating is not showing correct in join mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to get average ratings using "group by" statement in MySQL but it is showing unexpected data (ratings only), I want to get list of submitted forms along with ratings.

Here is my table "nps_ans":

```
id  config_id(owner of form)    contact_mapping_id      mobile_no(users)    question    rating
1   2                           68                      3333333333          abc         8
2   2                           69                      4444444444          xyz         NULL
3   1                           68                      3333333333          jdu         3
```

Here is my "addo_contacts" table:

```
contactId   name
68          abc
69          xyz
```

Here is my table "addo_contacts_mapping" table:

```
id  contactId   email
1   68          abc@gmail.com
2   69          xyz@gmail.com
```

I tried achieving it with following code but ratings are not showing as expected.

```
$this->db->select("na.config_id,contact_mapping_id,na.mobile_no,ac.name,acm.gender,acm.email,")
    ->from("nps_ans na")
    ->join("addo_contacts ac", "ac.mobileNo=na.mobile_no")
     ->join("addo_contacts_mapping acm", "acm.contactId=ac.contactId")
     ->group_by("na.contact_mapping_id")
    ->group_by("na.mobile_no")
```

Comment: You can not select plain column values that are not part of your grouping to begin with. (MySQL in fault tolerant mode would _allow_ this, but you would get a value from one “random” record inside the group for those columns.)

Comment: And what is up with this data structure in the first place …? Why are contact name and contact email kept in separate tables to begin with? And why is the phone number part of your first table, instead of being mapped via the contact ID as well? Unless a contact could have two different phone numbers in your first table, this should be placed _in_ the contact info table as well.

Comment: @CBroe: i not created db,i am just working,kindly give me solution for this

Comment: This isn't plain php; you're using some sort of database class. It might help to say which one. Also, in your code you are joining using `ac.mobileNo` which doesn't exist in your sample data. And in your explanation you say you want an average and then say you want a list. So it's hard to know even what output you'd like. It might be worth trying to clarify by showing an 'expected output' table.